# lmer syntax questions

Tags: r, syntax

I am trying to do some mixed/fixed effect modelling, and have come across the `lme4` package, which includes the `lmer` function. But I am really confused about the syntax to be honest, and I have tried looking into the documentation, but I am not sure I fully understand, and also it seems like the ones I have differ a bit.

For example I have something like this:

```
T <- lmer(Y ~ Treatment + 0 + (1|Block) + (1|Subblock), data = D, REML = FALSE)
T1 <- lmer(Y ~ 1 + (1|Block) + (1|Subblock), data = D, REML = FALSE)
```

Can anyone "quickly" explain what this actually means ? Like, the 1's before the | means that the variable `Block` or `Subblock` should be treated as random effect, and `Treatment` is a fixed effect. But what about the single 1's and 0's ? Can I change the 1's before the | to 0's, and if so, what does that mean ?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet

Comment: maybe you can say more (in comments or in your question) about what documentation sources you have that seem to differ/disagree with each other?

Comment: **This question is related to programming syntax. It is on-topic on _Stack Overflow_,  but off-topic on _Cross Validated_ and should therefore _not_ be migrated.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Y ~ Treatment + 0 + (1|Block) + (1|Subblock)
```

(I wouldn't recommend using `T` as variable name in R, by the way ...)

- `0+Treatment` denotes a fixed effect of treatment, in "dummy" or "treatment" coding (the default), *with the intercept suppressed* (that's what the `0` denotes here); in other words, you will have one fixed-effect parameter per level of `Treatment`, equal to the expected value for observations in that treatment.
- `(1|Block) + (1|Subblock)` denotes random variation in the intercept of the model (that's what `1` means here) among blocks and among subblocks: it assumes that subblocks are uniquely coded (e.g. A1, A2, ..., B1, B2, ... rather than 1, 2, ... , 1, 2, ...)

```
Y ~ 1 + (1|Block) + (1|Subblock)
```

Same as above, but now there is no fixed effect of treatment - only an experiment-wide intercept value.

You would compare these two models (e.g. with `anova()` to do a likelihood ratio test or `AIC()`) to test the statistical significance of `Treatment`.

See the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) or [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet) for more details on `lme4` syntax.

PS changing `1` to `0` in the random effects specification would be weird; *if* it worked at all (which I'm not sure it would), it would in principle be equivalent to suppressing that random effect ("what varies across groups? nothing") - which would be easier to do by just leaving that RE out of the formula altogether ...